# different result when a function run as interactive command and run as eval-expression

Tags: emacs, command

I have a elisp function to change the `default-directory` of scratch buffer,

```
(defun sd/test ()
  (interactive)
  (print (current-buffer))
  (setq default-directory "~/"))
```

I put this code in scratch buffer, whose default directory is `~/temp`, and I try to use this function to change it to `~/`.

The strange thing is that this function does not work when I call it from `M-x`. the defaut-directory isn't changed. 
However, when I call it from `M-:`, `eval-expression`, it works. the default-directory changed.

So why the first way to call the function doesn't take effect?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that the issue is  I mapped `M-x` to `counsel-M-x`, which is a thirty party package. this is the issue of counsel package. 
After removing the counsel package,  the `M-x` now works same as `M-:`